# Please Help with Audio Drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, touchscreen

I have HP X2 Detachable Laptop with Windows 10 64Bit pre-installed. It has an emmc drive of 32GB and an Intel Atom 1.44Ghz Processor with 2GB RAM. Needless to mention that the above specs are not enough to drive the existing OS came pre-installed. I am desperate to move on to Ubuntu 16.04 and convert it into Macbuntu. I have even tried the same by booting it via. USB. All worked great, except audio drivers. Also, touch screen is working fine, but I am unable to expand and contract using two finger gestures.

Laptop has Microphone and Speaker drivers of intel sst audio device (wdm), which, unfortunately, are not working at all with Ubuntu.

Please share the info over compatible audio and touch drivers and help me out to complete the switch over. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into?noredirect=1&lq=1 to begin with.

Comment: With specs that bad, I suggest you use Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi...running command cat /proc/asound/cards is resulting in "no soundcards"....please suggest as I wanted to stick to Ubuntu as primary driver...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another audio channel in

### settings > audio?

At my PC there are 3 channels/devices and if you take a false one there is simply no audio working. So for example I have got an audio-interface (containing two channels, a digital, a analog) wich I use on the analog channel and my mainboard audio. If I would use my mainboard audio there would be no sound. I had a similar problem about two months ago. Just try different settings out.
I hope this will help you.